# Virtual environment not setting properly in python using python setup.py develop

Tags: python, git, python-2.7, subprocess

I am taking 2 branches of the same repo as input. Then I checkout the 1st branch & do python setup.py develop  and then run the test scripts. 
Then I stash the changes and then checkout the 2nd branch & do python setup.py develop  and then run the test scripts again. And finally I compare the results . 
  Here , I am getting both the results same . I tried to check in logs , but everything looks fine. Can anybody suggest what may be the issue?

```
    execute_git_command('git stash')
    execute_git_command('git checkout ' + branch_one)
    comment_requirements_file()
    execute_git_command('python setup.py develop') #setup_virtual_env
    branch1_script_results_list = run_the_scoring_script(branch_one)
    execute_git_command('python setup.py develop --uninstall')

    execute_git_command('git stash')
    execute_git_command('git checkout ' + branch_two)
    comment_requirements_file()
    execute_git_command('python setup.py develop') #setup_virtual_env
    branch2_script_results_list = run_the_scoring_script(branch_two)
    execute_git_command('python setup.py develop --uninstall')

    print branch1_script_results_list
    print branch2_script_results_list

def execute_git_command(git_command):
    pr = subprocess.Popen(git_command,
                          shell=True,
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                          stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    (out, error) = pr.communicate()
```

Answer (score 0):

`python setup.py develop` does not setup a virtual environment. It installs the package inplace. If `python` refers to the system python then your package will be available to the system globally.

I'm not sure how well the uninstall option works for `setup.py`. You could try `pip install -e .` to install the package inplace. And `pip uninstall <package_name>` to uninstall it.

To run a command in a given virtualenv, you could use [`vex` utility](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vex):

```
$ vex <virtualenv_name> <command>
```

Or to activate a virtualenv for a given shell session, call `workon` shell function from [`virtualenvwrapper` package](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

```
$ workon <virtualenv_name>
$ <command1>
$ <command2>
$ deactivate
```

You could [use `tox` to run the tests in different virtualenvs](https://testrun.org/tox/latest/).